# ElasticSearch. Total number of unique terms in an index

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to access the total number of terms in an index through ES API?
I need to estimate the prior probability of a term occurring in the index:

```
total_term_frequency/total_terms_in_index
```

I can access `ttf` but no total number of terms stored in the index.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [cardinality aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) is what you're looking for.

For example:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "term_count": {
         "cardinality": {
            "field": "doc_text"
         }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 7,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 4,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "term_count": {
         "value": 161
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used to play around with it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/d5625c80946f332718b0fa166bba27efd264b76e

Comment: Thanks! But as I understand this returns the count of unique terms, correct? I need a count of all the terms in a given index for given fields. This can only be one time thing to find out the value, so I don't care about the performance.

Comment: Yeah, it returns the number of unique terms for the specified field.